# Would it be on topic to ask for a comparison of common wire insulation materials and their relative merits?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

After seeing [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459873/stiff-shape-retaining-insulated-wires-vs-floppy-ones-which-bounce-back-ar), I got to thinking about how I am not aware of any resources on selecting wire insulation materials here, and I feel like that might be a good resource to have on EE.SE. However, since what I'm looking for is a relatively broad comparison of both objective ("it can withstand temperatures up to 500°C") and subjective ("it's much more flexible than other insulation materials") qualities of a wide variety of materials, I'm beginning to feel like it might not be suited for this site, hence asking this on meta.

Would this question be worth writing up at all, or would it be better suited for some other part of the internet?

Comment: A question like that topic could make a decent community wiki.  At least, it could have a wiki answer which compiles the information across multiple materials.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I went ahead and [asked the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459934/comparative-merits-of-wire-insulation-materials) then. I considered starting the answer myself, but I don't think I know enough about the topic to actually give much in the way of an answer.